# error: no suitable method found for setQuery(com.google.firebase.firestore.Query,Class<Note>)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to get data from the FirebaseFirestore and implement it in a cardview.

**This is my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Notebook");

    //notebookref is my collection name in firebase. 
    private NoteAdapter adapter;

    TextView tv_id;
    TextView tv_attend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv_id=findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        tv_attend=findViewById(R.id.tv_attend);

        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("attend", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_one);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

I get this following error:

```
error: no suitable method found for setQuery(com.google.firebase.firestore.Query,Class<Note>)
```

Seems like I am issue with: FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder().setQuery(query, Note.class).build();

Any pointers about how to deal with this issue?

Comment: hi @jai can you add the steps about how you got this error? This will help people to understand the problem better and help you in more efficient way.
You can read more about how to form a good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you have any error with this line `Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("attend", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);` ?

Comment: no i do not have any error on that line

Comment: .setQuery(query, Note.class)    This is the only line i have an error on

Comment: Is this dependency required?   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you import for `Query`. You should import

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
```

More details

```
orderBy(String field, Query.Direction direction)
```

Creates and returns a new Query that's additionally sorted by the specified field, optionally in descending order instead of ascending.

Ref. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query

Confirm your dependencies accordingly

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
}
```

Ref. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: On importing this , the line -   Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("attend", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
shows the error - error: cannot find symbol variable Direction

Comment: orderBy(String field, Query.Direction direction),,, this is exactly what i tried and it is showing the same error - error: cannot find symbol variable Direction

Comment: Recheck import, I edited it. Also, if your app not showing error for Query then it should not any error for Query.Direction as its an Enum.

Comment: Once i change my import the query works alright but it again goes back to my first error where .setQuery(query, Note.class) shows the same error

Comment: YES, i have all these dependencies, it is still showing this error - error: cannot find symbol variable Direction on this line - Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("attend", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

Answer (score 0):

I had to change :
FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder()
to : 
FirestoreRecyclerOptions options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder()